# Simplify R code to import big data as character

Tags: r

I am currently using the code below very often to import a big dataset into R and forcing it to treat everything as character in order to avoid the truncation of rows. The code seems to work well, but I was wondering whether any of you knows how it could be simplified or improved to so it doesn't get so repetitive each time I need to do it.

```
    library(readr)
    library(stringr)

    dataset.path <- choose.files(caption = "Select dataset", multi = FALSE)
    data.columns <- read_delim(dataset.path, delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE, n_max = 0)
    data.coltypes <- c(rep("c", ncol(data.columns)))
    data.coltypes <- str_c(data.coltypes, collapse = "")
    dataset <- read_delim(dataset.path, delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE, col_types = data.coltypes)
```

Comment: Code gets repetitive? --> Write a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @Roland has suggested, you should write a function. here is one possibility:

```
foo <- function(){
    require(readr)

    dataset.path <- choose.files(caption = "Select dataset", multi = FALSE)
    data.columns <- read_delim(dataset.path, delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE, n_max = 0)
    data.coltypes <- paste(rep("c", ncol(data.columns)), collapse = "")
    dataset <- read_delim(dataset.path, delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE, col_types = data.coltypes)
}
```

you can then just call `foo()` whenever you need to read a database in using this method.

your two liner:

```
data.coltypes <- c(rep("c", ncol(data.columns)))
data.coltypes <- str_c(data.coltypes, collapse = "")
```

can be collapsed into just one line and only using base R `paste` instead of `str_c` in the `stringr` package.